# Is this as a relative pronoun?

Tags: grammar

> The scene was not without a mixture of awe, such **as** must always
>   invest the spectacle of guilt and shame in a fellow-creature, before
>   society shall have grown corrupt enough to smile, instead of
>   shuddering at it.
>  (Nathaniel Hawthorne,The Scarlet Letter)

‘As’ seems to take the role of relative pronoun, and as-clause modifies ‘a mixture of awe.’ Is this right understanding?

Comment: **1)** *Awe such as* is a permitted variant of *such awe as*, which I would take to be a comparative construction like *same ... as* or *as ... as* or *more ... than*. I haven't gotten to McCawley's Ch. 20 yet! **2)** Your suggestion is certainly consistent with the *as* use raised by @FumbleFingers in your earlier [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/7347/32). **3)** Check the last paragraph of [this](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/equally.html).

Comment: By the way, the whatever-it-is modifies *awe*, not *mixure*.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't like to go out on a limb here (you're probably more familiar than I am with such archaic/pseudo-archaic forms), but I don't see how it's possible for **as** to refer back to anything other than the complete phrase **a mixture of awe**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *How* it's possible is easy: The scene was mixed with the kind of awe which always invests &c. *That* that is the proper reading is hard, but a scene being invested with a *mixture* is to my mind bathetic.

Comment: @StoneyB: I guess. I don't really recognise or understand this usage of *a mixture of X*, where ***X*** isn't explicitly *mixed **with** something else*. I assume it's either a genuine archaism, or an attempt to appear so.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think it's an archaism; it's just an instance of what the linguigeeks call a ['deverbal noun'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deverbal_noun). Usually the distinction is clear from context or defined by the accompanying syntactic paraphernalia, but in cases like this it's idiosyncratic: you look at *mixture* and your inner lexicographer says "noun", I look at it and my inner grammarian says "verbal".

Comment: @StoneyB: *My* innner grammarian just says the whole sentence is ridiculously "top-heavy". Unless I'm parsing it wrong, I seem to be looking at the structure *A, B (modifying A), C (modifying B), D (modifying C).* Maybe not exactly a "garden path sentence", but it certainly seems to meander along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that 'as' in question is a relative pronoun.

>
6   formal  used to refer only to people or things of a particular group or kind

**such ... as/who/that**

*Such individuals who take up this role often find life frustrating.*

**such of something/somebody as**

*Such of you as wish to leave may do so now.*
>

source: Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English.

'Such' is a pronoun and used for 'such awe'.