# Is the second ”as” here a relative pronoun?

Tags: grammar

The sentence goes like this.

> a) Rogers said his attorneys have the funding to " devote as much time **as** is necessary to adequately represent their clients.

In a lot of “as ... as...” constructions the second “as” functions as a conjunction. As in

> b) I need to run as fast as everyone else does.

But I feel like it isn’t the case in a) and I can rewrite it in the following way. Am I right?

> c) Rogers said his attorneys have the funding to " devote as much time **that** is necessary to adequately represent their clients.

This post doesn’t resolve my question because it isn’t about the “as... as...” construction.[1]: [Is this as a relative pronoun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7439/is-this-as-a-relative-pronoun?rq=1)

Comment: No: "as" is never a relative pronoun, though it does occur is similar constructions, as in _He phoned home every day, [as he'd promised to do]_  ~ _He phoned home every day, [which he'd promised to do]_. But your examples are comparative constructions where the preposition "as" has a comparative clause as its complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't rephrase it with **as...that** because then it is ungrammatical.

I think this sentence is still exactly the same structure as every other **as...as**.

How much time will they take?  **As** much **as** is necessary.
How fast will I run?  **As** fast **as** everyone else.

It's the same structure: we're describing the amount of something by comparing it to something else.

You could rephrase it using *that* into something like

> We will take all the time that is necessary

but that changes the structure, although the meaning is still baseically the same.

Comment: Consider substituting a comparative: ***more** [time] **than** is necessary*; ***faster than** everyone else*.