# What is the formal expression for ‘bin hurt’?

Tags: past-participles, eye-dialect

> "Look there," said Hagrid, "see that stuff shinin' on the ground?
> Silvery stuff? That's unicorn blood. There's a unicorn in there **bin
> hurt** badly by summat. This is the second time in a week. I found one
> dead last Wednesday. We're gonna try an' find the poor thing. We might
> have ter put it out of its misery."
>
> (*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*)

What is the formal expression for ‘bin hurt’?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> There's a unicorn in there *that's* **been** hurt badly by **something**.

*Bin* is just eye dialect for *been*.  The word itself isn't informal, though the omission of *that's* and the use of *summat* instead of *something* are.

Comment: +1 The omission of *that* was discussed [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/7347/32).

Comment: *Bin* is also a word itself. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bin_1?q=bin

Comment: @Tristan: That's not the meaning of the word _bin_ in this context.

Comment: I wouldn't call the word "informal", either, but it does show that the character doesn't have the most formal enunciation – as does _an’_ and _ter_.

Comment: J.R., I realise that. It's still worth knowing that *bin* is also a word.

Comment: Well ... I'd say using *summat* instead of *something* is a regional English dialect. As far as I know, this is never used in America.

Comment: What's "eye dialect"?

Comment: @starsplusplus http://homepage.ntlworld.com/vivian.c/SpellingNovel/EyeDialect.htm

Answer (score 4):

What he means is: there is a unicorn in there that has **been hurt** badly by something.